# How to query current tab name of tabbed GUI terminals (any)

Tags: terminal, xfce4-terminal, tabs

Using tmux, I have implemented a work flow in which I set a virtual home-directory for each "window" I create in tmux. I can query the name of the current window with `tmux display-message -p '#W'`. So I pretty easily implement my system as shown in the code below. You get the idea.

**QUESTION**
I would like to do the same kind of "per tab home directory" in a GUI terminal. But I need to query the name of the current tab so I can look up the home-dir in my simple DB. I can't find a way to query tab names. I prefer xfce4-terminal, but I am open to others. I am also open to using the
Thanks!
--Myles

```
alias cdh 'cd `~/bin/get_tmux_window_home_dir`'
```

```
% cat ~/bin/get_tmux_window_home_dir
#!/usr/bin/ruby
$VERBOSE = nil
window = `tmux display-message -p '#W'`.chomp
if ! $?.success?
  STDERR.puts "Error: tmux display-message -p '#W' failed."
  print 'XXXXX'
  exit 1
end
db_file = "/home/#{ENV['USER']}/.config/tmux_window_home_dir/tmux_window_home_dir.csv"
db = {}
if File.exists?(db_file)
  File.readlines(db_file).each do |l|
    s = l.split(',')
    db[s[0]] = s[1]
  end
end
if db[window]
  print db[window]
else
  STDERR.puts "Error: There is no home directory set for tmux window name '#{window}'"
  print 'XXXXX'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a little more poking around before submitting the question and found:

1. In xfce4-terminal, the current tab becomes the window name
2. The $WINDOWID env var contains the window id of the current window
3. `xwininfo -id $WINDOWID` gives info about the window, including the window name which can be easily extracted

So I think the above has all of the information needed.

Comment: Not only nobody replied to your comment, but you've also been downvoted.
And yet, you were kind enough to provide the answer you found on your own (which is what brought me here). Thanks for sharing and helping at least one stranger on the internet